# Junit how to get the variable which is in the parent class?

Tags: android, junit

I have a class like this way:

```
Class A extends B
Class B extends C

Class C{
    protected ArrayList<Dialog> variable;
}
```

And I want to do Class A's JUnit test, I want to get the instance of variable in Class C, is there a way to do this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

you must add getter and setter to class B then you can have access to variable inside class A
like this

```
class C{
 protected Object variable;
}
class B extends C{
protected void setObject(Object obj)
   this.variable = obj;
}

protected Object getObject(){
   return this.variable;
}
}

class A extends B{
}
```